# How to add in .as with a package int MXML

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, mxml

How to add in .as with a class extends Sprite ??
  We created the Easy1 in Flash Professional to create a live streaming video viaFMS for 2 users and now we want to combine easy1 into HelloFlerry to invoke Flash-Java nativeprocess.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"  
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="600" minHeight="400" 
                       xmlns:flerry="net.riaspace.flerry.*" 
                       xmlns:easy1="Easy1.*"> 
    <easy1:Easy1 label="Easy1"/> 
    <easy1:Script source="Easy1.as"/> 



package Easy1
    {
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
        import flash.net.NetConnection;
        import flash.net.NetStream;
        import flash.media.Camera;
        import flash.media.Microphone;
        import flash.media.Video;

        public class Easy1 extends Sprite
        {
            private var nc:NetConnection;
            private var good:Boolean;
            private var rtmpNow:String;
            private var nsIn:NetStream;
            private var nsOut:NetStream;
            private var cam:Camera;
            private var mic:Microphone;
            private var vidLocal:Video;
            private var vidStream:Video;
            public function Easy1()
            {
                trace("Hello testing");
                rtmpNow = "rtmp://localhost/LiveStreams";
                nc=new NetConnection();
                nc.connect(rtmpNow);
                nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,checkCon);
                setCam();
                setMic();
                setVideo();
            }
            private function checkCon(e:NetStatusEvent):void
            {
                good = e.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success";
                if (good)
                {
                    nsOut = new NetStream(nc);
                    nsOut.attachAudio(mic);
                    nsOut.attachCamera(cam);
                    nsOut.publish("left","live");
                    nsIn = new NetStream(nc);
                    nsIn.play("right");
                    vidStream.attachNetStream(nsIn);
                }
            }
            private function setCam()
            {
                cam = Camera.getCamera();
                cam.setKeyFrameInterval(9);
                cam.setMode(240,180,15);
                cam.setQuality(0,80);
            }
            private function setMic()
            {
                mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
                mic.gain = 85;
                mic.rate = 11;
                mic.setSilenceLevel(15,2000);
            }


            private function setVideo()
            {
                vidLocal = new Video(cam.width,cam.height);
                addChild(vidLocal);
                vidLocal.x = 15;
                vidLocal.y = 30;
                vidLocal.attachCamera(cam);
                vidStream = new Video(cam.width,cam.height);
                addChild(vidStream);
                vidStream.x=(vidLocal.x+ cam.width +10);
                vidStream.y = vidLocal.y;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: very vague question with way too much code. Consider correcting your grammar and including only the required bits of code.

Answer (score 1):

MXML is a template, which effectively creates package declaration for you, so once you try to add one of your own, you will duplicate package definitions, which is not allowed.

You can't also declare classes inside <Script> tag. The code from <Script> tag goes into methods and properties definition block of the class.

If you must declare package and class - use *.as file for that. If you want them to be declared for you using MXML template - well, then don't declare them yourself. You can't have both at the same time.